# Referencing an associated ActiveRecord model's attributes efficiently (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, foreign-key-relationship

Say I have a Post and User model where the User `has_many` posts.  The User model has a `name` property.

Say I want to display each `User#name` in a query of Post objects with something like `Post.all.each {|post| puts post.user.name}`.  This works, but Rails issues a Database query for each of the N posts to look up each individual user's name like

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
```

Is there a way to tell Rails it can look this up through a join rather than issuing a separate query for each instance?  If I try to use standard joins like `Post.all.joins(:user).select('posts.*,users.name')`, the ActiveRecord::Relation object comes back appropriately, but during the iteration a new queries is still issued for each Post in the row.

Comment: Try Post.includes(:user) Read about includes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
Post.includes(:user)
```

It's called eager loading , performance wise this should only issue two DB queries ([check docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations))

Docs recommend using `Joins` instead when you need to apply conditions on loading (e.g Posts for users with names starting with 's')